# Adding specific text to any bold text in Word file

Tags: microsoft-word, find-and-replace

Can you help me how to add word " (correct)" after every bold word, in MS Word?

For example, if I have the following text:

> This is my **example** text.

how do I convert it to:

> This is my **example (correct)** text.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Of course - with Find & Replace option I can find words in bold, no problem with that. But I don't know how to add some word (like in my example) after word with bold formatting, in whole document.

Comment: I don't know well Word, but try something like: Find: `(example)` Replace:`\1 (correct)` or `$1 (correct)`

Comment: If you're looking to replace **aa bb** by **aa bb (correct)**, this is not possible with Word's non-greedy wildcard search. You'll need VBA, or to use another product than Word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Find & Replace with Use wildcards switched on. Then put `(<*>)` into the Find what field, and type control-b while still in that field to search for bold text. Type `\1 (correct)` into the Replace with field. This will replace all bold words, but not words with a mix of bold and non-bold characters.

Comment: This will replace each word separately, not do a bold sentence as one.

Comment: Correct. Which is exactly what the OP asked for...